# What causes java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: when trying to deploy .ear in weblogic?

Tags: java, eclipse, web, weblogic, ear

I am trying to deploy an EAR file. I am new to weblogic. I am using oracle enterprise pack for eclipse. I have a running weblogic server. I created an Enterprise Application Project
My application.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
   <display-name>My App</display-name>
<module>
<ejb>appEJB.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
<web>
  <web-uri>app.war</web-uri>
  <context-root>app</context-root>
</web>
</module>
</application>
```

my weblogic-application.xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic- application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.1/weblogic-application.xsd">
<!--weblogic-version:10.3.3-->
<wls:application-param>
    <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
    <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
</wls:application-param>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

I get the error Module named 'EARNAME' failed to deploy. See Error log.
The error log has this stack Trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:190)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:506)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1466)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3108)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Files/OracleWebLogic/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/../../../modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.3.0.jar
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.pathToURLs(LoaderHandler.java:751)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:147)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1575)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(MarshalledObject.java:142)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$6.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1513)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.unwrap(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1505)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$500(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$7.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1548)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.unwrap(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1544)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:771)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:589)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:477)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:473)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

What could be the cause of this failur to deploy? I know the server is running and when I successfully access the gui at localhost:7001/console

I exported the .ear file to the autodeploy folder. Also put a module (.jar) in it.

New Exception:

```
 java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:190)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:506)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1466)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3108)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

 Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.init(EJBModule.java:332)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:167)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:285)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:298)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:330)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:1221)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:367)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find ejb-jar with uri appEJB.jar in ear at C:\Users\Jonathan.Rosenski\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\EAR\beadep\base_domain\EAR\split_src

at weblogic.ejb.spi.EJBJar.<init>(EJBJar.java:81)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.buildClassFinder(EJBModule.java:199)
at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.init(EJBModule.java:311)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a problem caused by a space in a directory name.  Looking at the error message:

```
    Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: 
    no protocol:
 Files/OracleWebLogic/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/../../../modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.3.0.jar
```

It seems that the jar file is being referenced by URL as "file://c:/Program Files/OracleWebLogic..." and the space in "Program Files" is causing the exception.

Can you try moving your Install to a different directory, like c:/OracleWebLogic?

Comment: I will try that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed to directory at c:/Oracle but my Eclipse OEPE was not uninstalled correctly I think and the server home is still pointing to the old directory c:/Program Files... So i am working on fixing this. Do you know where to set the server home in Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Eclipse OEPE.  I'd guess that the best place to start looking for the Oracle plugin's settings would be under "Window > Preferences".

Comment: Not sure if this helps: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18692/installjdev.htm#BABHHEII

Comment: I am looking for where you set the server directory home like c:/oracle/middleware/wlsserver/server . Actually I tried to uninstall the oepe plugin, but there were dependencies missing so I am running on a clean eclipse now and re-installing the plugin

Comment: I finally fixed the configuration issues and retried! I got a different exception now (which i posted as an edit to question), which makes me think that the previous problem was solved by your solution and now I am doing something wrong. I am searching for possible solutions and to see if these problems are unrelated

Comment: I found this which i guess the answer to the new exception, I need to create this file: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2448292

Answer (score 1):

This might help somebody.

Remove all occurrences of "**wls:**" from **weblogic.xml** (in your case it is weblogic-application.xml) & hopefully it should run fine.

At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from EJK's correct answer above, I'd just like to add the following work around for anyone getting a similar error.

The way to resolve this is to repace all **spaces** in the path name with **%20**, and is a consequence of this Java nuance: [MaformedURLException Bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4496398).

For me, this issue arose when trying to specify java VM arguments - more specifically, when trying to specify a codebase for my registry whose path contained spaces.

```
rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/Users/matt/Path With Spaces/"
```

As the path is in fact treated as a URL, the correct path should be:

```
rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/Users/matt/Path%20With%20Spaces/"
```

For completeness, I'd like to point out that this error will not actually be thrown when the rmiregistry is run, but when you try run a program that connects to the registry.